# Importing a remote table into a remote mysql server

Tags: mysql, ssh, navicat, import-from-csv

I want to import a large csv/txt/tsv file into a mysql server database. The file is sitting on a remote machine at University which I have access to via ssh. The mysql database (and server) are sitting on the same remote machine. I have been trying to use Navicat to import this text file into the remote database to no avail.

Is there a simple way to do this without first downloading the (very large) file then uploading it to mysql?

Answer (score 2):

use [SQL YOG](http://www.webyog.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You may write simple bash script that will convert csv/txt/other to sql.

Answer (score -2):

[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) will do what you want. It can handle both local (to the server) and local (to you) files.